# vb form in startup script does not display

Tags: vb.net

I have a program written in vb.net that contains a form. The form has 5 label controls and 1 button. I am using this program as my startup script file on my network (server 2008r2). When a user signs in to one of the servers the script executes and runs fine until it gets to the `form.showdialog` command. At that point nothing happens.

I have a try/catch like below:

```
Try
    ...write message1 to file in SQL database
    Form1.ShowDialog()
    ...write message2 to file in SQL database
Catch ex As Exception
    ...write error message to file in an SQL database
End Try
```

`message1` writes fine and that's it.

Now if I run the exe script file directly from one of the servers by double clicking on it the form displays fine.

If anyone can provide some insight I sure would appreciate it. This one has me stumped.

Comment: What is the error is being returned to the Catch block?  Have it write the error and stack trace out to a file and then post that.

Comment: I'd suspect a thread/race condition. Your program may not yet have access to the UI. If your ShowDialog is in the Load event try moving it to the Shown event. ... Not sure why you are calling ShowDialog anyway unless you are loading another form from the startup form.

Answer (score 0):

`.ShowDialog` causes the application to wait for the form being shown to no longer be shown. An example would be a prompt for a value, the form that threw the prompt would not progress past the `.ShowDialog` while the prompt remained open.

Since it sounds like you're wanting the code to progress without user involvement, my thought would be to:
- Move the code prior to `Form1.ShowDialog` into the Load code (`Handles MyBase.Load`) for Form1

- Make sure Form1 is the Startup Form for the application
- Add all code currently following `Form1.ShowDialog` to the `.Shown` event code for Form1